# Troubles with displaying cards components from function [React-Bootstrap]

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, web-development-server

I m running into some trouble trying to render bootstrap elements with ReactJS script.
To give you my user case, I got to display cards depending on some list of data created from DB. However when I loop to create my 'card's to show in a "card-desk", I observe on my browser the "card-deck" is correctly generated by react  while cards elements in the loop do not to seemed generated by react in the rendered page.
So far I tried with lists of data to avoid mixing problem with DB

```
function DisplayUnes(){
 var i = 0
 const nbrArticle = 3
 const items = []

 const idUnes =
 [
  1,
  2,
  3
 ]

 const titleUnes =
 [

 ]

 const dateUnes =
 [

 ]

 const bodyUnes =
 [

 ]

 //string href to github storage
 const imgUnes =
 [

 ]

for(i = 0; i<nbrArticle; i++) {
 items.push(

  <div className="card" key={idUnes}>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h5 className="card-title">{titleUnes[i]}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">{bodyUnes[i]}</p>
      <a>{dateUnes[i]}</a>
      <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}

return (items)
}
```

... later in the code I use the tag:

```
<main>
<h1>A la une</h1>
<div className="card-columns">
<DisplayUnes />
</div>
</main>
```

I have tried other approach like calling the function, storing the generated html and displaying it in the "card-columns" block. It seems the problem comes from the loop.. When I inspect rendered code on a browser, jsx id are not generated for elements in

Would you have any idea on how to fix this problem?
I verified multiple times all necessary dependencies are installed (using nextjs, react-bootstrap) but if someone is able to provide me a recap of them, it might still be useful.

Thx in advance for your time,
Have a nice day,
Benjamin

Comment: why is `items = []` declared as `const` if we are pushing values into it.

Answer (score 0):

use this
`let i = 0` instead of this `var i=0`;
and

```
  for (const [index, value] of idUnes.entries()) {
     items.push(
 <div className="card" key={index}>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h5 className="card-title">{titleUnes[index]}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">{bodyUnes[index]}</p>
      <a>{dateUnes[index]}</a>
      <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

)
}

and

change `const items = []` to `let items = []`.